# What's going on in this substitution?

Tags: regex, perl

Could I get some help figuring out what's going on?

How does the .xnext end up at the beginning of the string?

```
    [237]  > cat /tmp/text.txt
    xtop.xnext|sig 12345
    [238]  > perl -p -e 's/\.xnext\\|/.xnext./;' /tmp/text.txt
    .xnext.xtop.xnext|sig 12345
```

Comment: You have one too many backslashes before the pipe.

Comment: True, but why does it put a '.xnext' at the beginning? Something basic about s/// that I'm missing?  Or, how does it decide to do something to ^ (start or line) (assuming that's what happened)?

Comment: An empty alternative matches the empty string before the first character.

Comment: Because the now unescaped `|` introduces a regex alternation with the empty string, which matches immediately.

Comment: Cool. Thanks guys.  I meant to match the '|', but now I have effectively said "something or nothing" and the nothing was found at the beginning of the string.. perl magic :)

Answer (score 1):

In your regex, `|` is the "alternation" metacharacter and not a literal pipe character. So your pattern

```
\.xnext\\|
```

can either match the literal string `.xnext\`, which is what is specified on the left side of the alternation character, or

nothing, which is what is specified to the right side of the alternation.

So the beginning of your input string is a match for your regular expression pattern, and your substitution pattern `.xnext.` is prepended to your string.

The pattern you wanted to use was

```
\.xnext\|
```

which is how to specify the literal string `.xnext|`.